# Change select string on other string

Tags: php

I have String "YesNoNoYesNo"
I would like change all Yes on No and No on Yes

```
function ChangeWord($string)
 {
  if(strstr($string,'Yes')) {

    return $result = str_replace('No', 'Yes', $string);
   }
elseif(strstr($string,'Yes'))
{
    return $result = str_replace('Yes', 'No', $string);
}

 }
```

It not working, because change all No on Yes but not Yes on No

Should out "NoYesYesNoYes"

Comment: I can't use  array, only raw string

Comment: Why can't you use an array? That's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You have to use a temporary string. At first change all Yes to Tmp, then change No to Yes, then Tmp to No. Done :)

Comment: @Sparky256, no there is no function called `str.replace`. In fact you can't even use a `.` character in a function name.

Comment: @Chris. Sorry, I meant the generic function '.replace()'. 'str' can be any named variable. 'str_replace()' only works if it is already a declared function.

Comment: @Sparky256 Why would you pass another string variable as an argument then? `str_replace` will work as it's a PHP built-in. `$str.replace` won't for many reasons. Firstly it's the completely wrong syntax for calling a function on an object. Secondly PHP strings (or any scalar types for that matter) don't have functions.

Comment: @Chris. I work with PHP 5.3, and not that much, so I guess I am behind the times. I mostly work with css and javascript/jquery/node.js.